# Oracle table type data to XML format

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Thanks Friend, a little more edit.
I have data in a table type, 
Oracle 11g PLSQL.
inside that table type another table type , and inside another table type
for example

**header_table_type**  has

```
columns header_id (Number)
item_name (varchar2)
item_type (varchar2)
service_detail **(Service_table_type)**
```

**service_table_type** has

```
columns service_name (Varchar2),
service_id (varchar2)
service_details **(service_term_table_type)**
```

**service_term_table_type** has

```
service_1 varchar2, 
service_2 varchar2 , 
service 2 varchar2.
```

My table_type has the structure as above mentioned . Is there any way to make this table_type into an XML format. for sending through a Web service.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course this is possible by using function

```
XMLTYPE()
```

Try this example

```
create type service_term_table_type as object (
  service_1 varchar2(30),
  service_2 varchar2(30),
  service_3 varchar2(30)
 )
/
create type service_table_type as object (
service_id varchar2(30),
service_details service_term_table_type
 )
/
 create type header_table_type as object (
   header_id number, 
   item_name varchar2(30),
   item_type varchar2(30), 
   service_detail service_table_type)
  /
 create table xml_example (a xmltype)
 /
 declare
 mytype  header_table_type:=header_table_type(1,'a','b',service_table_type('c',service_t erm_table_type('d','e','f')));
 x xmltype;
begin
  x:=xmltype(mytype);
  insert into xml_example values (x);
end;
```

Now you can see the result:

```
select substr(a,1,500) from xml_example;


<HEADER_TABLE_TYPE>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

  <HEADER_ID>1</HEADER_ID>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

  <tITEM_NAME>a</ITEM_NAME>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

  <ITEM_TYPE>b</ITEM_TYPE>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

  <SERVICE_DETAIL>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    <SERVICE_ID>c</SERVICE_ID>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

    <SERVICE_DETAILS>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

      <SERVICE_1>d</SERVICE_1>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

      <SERVICE_2>e</SERVICE_2>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

      <SERVICE_3>f</SERVICE_3>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

    </SERVICE_DETAILS>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

  </SERVICE_DETAIL>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

</HEADER_TABLE_TYPE>
```